# SSH local port forwarding for web traffic requires proxy configuration in browser settings?

Tags: ssh-tunneling, browser

I enabled SSH local port forwarding with a command `ssh -NL 8080:whatsmyip.org:80 <remote-sshd-machine>`. Now when I opened up a Firefox and navigated to `http://127.0.0.1:8080`, the web-page did not open. However, if I configured a HTTP proxy to `127.0.0.1` and port `8080` in Firefox network settings menu, then the web-page opened up and whatsmyip.org reported my remote SSH server IP address just as it should. Why did I need to configure proxy settings under browser to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

If what you're trying to do is using your remote SSH server as a SOCKS proxy for your browser, the ssh command you're looking for is:

```
ssh -N -D8080 <remote-sshd-machine>
```

This will start a SOCKSv4/5 proxy on localhost TCP port 8080, which allow you to browse any website with the IP address of the remote SSH server. If, however, you are trying to access a remote site (e.g. whatsmyip.org) via localhost, note the following:

1. The remote server must **not** use name-based virtual hosts. Name-based virtual hosting puts multiple different sites (e.g. example.com and example.org) on the same IP address. Differentiation between sites is done exclusively by the URL given in the browser, since both example.com and example.org would resolve to the same IP. In your case the remote server would look at the URL, which is `http://localhost` and probably produce an error or do something unpredictable (Apache tends to do this!), because it doesn't recognize the "localhost" domain name in its list of name-based virtual hosts.
2. The remote server must ignore the fact that the port number has changed from 80 to 8080. Normally most static HTML sites and web servers ignore this, however, some servers and web applications may try to redirect you to port 80, which will obviously break things for you.

If you truly wish to simulate the above (I didn't test this thoroughly, and I don't encourage you to make a habit of running ssh as root!), try this:

```
sudo ssh -N -L 127.0.0.1:80:whatsmyip.org:80 <remote-sshd-machine>
```

you need the sudo above, because you're asking the ssh client to listen on port 80, which is <1024 and is considered a privileged port, and only processes owned by root can bind to these ports. Also note that you cannot be running any other services on port 80 on your client (e.g. a web server). If you are, you will need to stop that service and release port 80 before you try this command.

Secondly, add the following line to your /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 whatsmyip.org www.whatsmyip.org
```

The first command will forward TCP port 80 on your local machine (SSH client) to port 80 on whatsmyip.org. The hosts file will ensure that when you ask for whatsmyip.org with your browser, that name resolves to your localhost. This way you are preserving the port number and the hostname that your browser will send to whatsmyip.org via your SSH tunnel. How do you know if the tunnel worked? whatsmyip.org should report the SSH server's (remote SSHd machine) IP address instead of your client's.